# Does the genie warlock's Bottled Respite ability let you perceive what happens outside?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, vision-and-light, extradimensional-space

I haven't been able to find any information about this, so my understanding is that you are completely oblivious to what's happening outside of the vessel while you're in it.

But thinking about flavor, it would make more sense for this feature to include a way of being called from outside, so am I missing something?

Comment: Since you are new it is worth considering that we don't always agree here and the first answer isn't always correct. Generally it is good advice to let a question run for 24 hours before accepting an answer, it gives other people a chance to vote on answers or create their own

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You can hear. Seeing is up to the DM's judgment.

The rules for *Bottled Respite* have the following statements :

> The interior of the vessel is an extradimensional space in the shape of a 20-foot-radius cylinder, 20 feet high, and resembles your vessel.

> While inside, you can hear the area around your vessel as if you were in its space.

This means that you can indeed hear around your vessel. For the question of whether you can see or not, it isn't as obvious.

If your vessel is an opaque container, it could make sense to not be able to see outside of it. If the container is not opaque, there isn't a clear explanation (no pun intended) as to whether or not the extradimensional space's walls imitate the outside area of your vessel, or if they simply imitate the container and nothing else.

In any case, the vessel being a magic item, we cannot simply decide of the "proper rules" of the item by using logic. Hearing what's around the vessel doesn't follow logic, after all. Because of that, it is up to the DM to decide whether creatures inside the vessel can or cannot see.

#### A possible oversight regarding "guests"

At level 10, the *Sanctuary Vessel* feature allows you to "invite" other creatures in the vessel :

> When you enter your Genie’s Vessel via the Bottled Respite feature, you can now choose up to five willing creatures that you can see within 30 feet of you, and the chosen creatures are drawn into the vessel with you.

The text states that "while inside, you can hear...", the "you" being the user of the ability. This does not cover whether other creatures currently inside the bottle can or cannot hear outside of it.

This means that whether another creature than the user of the vessel can or cannot hear or see outside of it is also up to the DM. After all, there is no proper explanation on whether the user can perceive the outside of the vessel in their mind or on the extradimensional space's walls themselves.

Comment: Given it specifically says you can hear, I don't think this is right. The lack of talk about sight almost certainly means you can't see, otherwise why only mention one?

Comment: @SeriousBri as much as that is an obvious logical interpretation, the lack of information makes it hard to tell for sure. Not mentioning sight could very well be intended, just as it could be another oversight. Maybe the designers intended it to depend on the container? Maybe they wanted to leave it ambiguous for DMs to rule it in cool ways depending on the container or the situation? Who knows.

Comment: Indeed, if you enter an oil lamp you probably can't see out, but a bottle might allow you to see. You are "entering the vessel" after all, it isn't just a straight teleportation to some pocket dimension. I'm not sure if "guests" can enter the bottle though? I think if so then interpreting "you" as "the warlock" is going to be super problematic, eg guests can stay in the bottle indefinitely and don't have to wait for a long rest to re-enter.

Comment: @user77842 at level 10, you get an ability that lets you invite creature into the vessel when you enter it. It's called "Sanctuary vessel", I'll edit my answer to include it. It does handle the case of guests staying stuck in the vessel, in a section I haven't quoted since it doesn't relate to the question. I do believe the ability is a straight teleportation to a pocket dimension though, as highlighted by "The interior of the vessel is an extradimensional space".

Comment: @Matthieu Ah yes, thanks for clarifying. There's a little unresolved mechanics between it being both inside and also extradimensional. I don't think we are supposed to understand it as teleportation, and more like "the bottle is bigger on the inside than on the outside".

Comment: @user77842 I think it's actually closer to how a *Bag of Holding* would work, in some regards. The vessel acts as a focus, which influences the spell's effects (such as the appearance of the extradimensional space), but things inside aren't actually in the object.

Comment: If creature are actually inside the object, I wonder if they could be seen from the outside...

Comment: If we go by *I Dream Of Jeannie* rules, you can see tiny people inside if you uncork the bottle and peer in, but moving it causes earthquakes inside as they're shaken around.

Answer (score 3):

### You can hear but cannot see.

The Bottled Respite ability says

> While inside, you can hear the area around your vessel as if you were in [the container's] space.

So that's clear enough. You are not totally oblivious; you can hear.

Because the bottle's interior is a magical extradimensional space, we can't trust our intuition about what does or doesn't get through to the inside. But since we're specifically told you can hear, and no other senses are mentioned, we can safely assume that means all other senses are blocked. You get sound from outside, but nothing else.